# Setting property of POJO from List in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a form to set values for bean. This form has a List, every address consist of street, city, zip. How to set value of street for example to street ?

Piece of code

```
//List
List<Address> addressList ; //with getter and setter

//Address POJO with getters and setters
private String city;

private String zipCode;

private String street;


//JSP
<form:form id="form" commandName="form" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
<c:forEach items="${form.addressList}" var="ad">
<input  value="${ad.street}" id="addressList"name="addressList.street" type="text"   />     
</c:forEach>
</form:form>


$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : $('#form').serialize(),
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
```

I'm sending form by ajax to controller. 
With List of Strings I'm getting in controller expected results, but with this POJO I'm getting null value.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You `addressList` is not a part of Form and you are reading it from form object.

```
<c:forEach items="${form.addressList}" var="ad">
```

It should be

```
<c:forEach items="${addressList}" var="ad">
```